# Android if else statement on an activity call for layout

Tags: java, javascript, android, if-statement

So guys i get a force close on this, it doesn't load anything on my LogCat i cant seem to find out whats wrong.. can anyone please tell me why is this happening i believe my logic is correct or is it not possible to declare an if else statement when calling for a layout to display? if not, can anyone tell me another way of doing this? it just opens a layout incase the keyword is taxi stored in my global variable which i just call anytime i want.

```
public class TaxiInfoWindowAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {

    private final View mContentsView;
    private Activity mActivity;
    public String title_value = (Holder.myValue).toString();

    public TaxiInfoWindowAdapter(Activity act){

        if(title_value.equals("Taxi")){
        mContentsView = act.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.taxi_info_window, null);
        mActivity = act;

        }else{
        mContentsView = act.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window, null);
        mActivity = act;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: probably `Holder.myValue` is null ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seem `Holder.myValue` is returning null. You should check for `null` before using it.

This should fix your issue.

```
public String title_value = "";

public TaxiInfoWindowAdapter(Activity act){
    if(Holder.myValue != null)
        title_value = Holder.myValue.toString();
    if(title_value.equals("Taxi")){
        // Rest of the code
```

Comment: If you use my code then it would work even if it is null. If its null then it would go to else part.